# Android: Cursor requery when replacing entire database

Tags: android, database, listview, cursor, refresh

I have a `ListActivity` which uses a `SimpleCursorAdapter` to display database content. I am  having problems getting the view refreshed when the underlying database changes.

As an experiment, I've added a call to `Cursor.requery()` in the activity's `onResume()`, for debugging, so all I have to do is flip to a different activity and back and it should force a refresh. I've also overridden `onContentChanged()`, for debugging. It transpires that `requery()` is being called, but this is not resulting in a call to `onContentChanged()`.

I suspect the cursor is using stale cached data. The operation which prompts the change actually involves wiping and replacing the whole database. Rather than simply requerying, I think I need to throw away the cursor and rebuild it from scratch.

I have tried closing and reopening the underlying database, in conjunction with `Cursor.requery()`, but the cursor doesn't seem to like having the db pulled from under its feet like this. (The list ends up empty.)

Edit: I've also tried calling `adapter.notifyDataSetChanged()` alongside the `requery()` in `onResume()`, but it makes no difference.

Any advice?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Solved by discarding the cursor, closing and reopening the database, and then recreating the cursor. I use an Observer to inform the activity of the database change, as follows:

```
@Override 
public void update(Observable observable, Object data) { 
    // database changed 
    runOnUiThread(new Runnable() { 
        @Override 
        public void run() { 
            stopManagingCursor(cursor); 
            dbAdapter.close(); 
            dbAdapter.open(); 
            cursor = getAccounts(); 
            startManagingCursor(cursor); 
            adapter.changeCursor(cursor); 
        } 
    }); 
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried calling notifyDataSetChanged() on your SimpleCursorAdapter from within your ListActivity's onResume() method?